# Black scrollbar appears when opening bootstrap modal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

When I'm opening a modal, a black/gray line appears beside the scrollbar:

[image: image1]

I know the problem is in bootstrap css somewhere, but i don't know where. I have tried going into inspect element and trying to fix it, but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem:

```
body.modal-open { 
    overflow: none; << Changed it to "none" from "inherit"
}
```